# Sonarqube synchronization error

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

I have created a custom rule for sonarqube in Java.
The rule is created and i can see that in the sonarqube UI.

Now the problem is when i try to check that rule from eclipse. I am getting error:
:Synchronization issue, has encountered some problem".
[image]

When I checked log from eclipse, i have this:

```
!ENTRY org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core 4 4 2016-04-18 10:02:36.641
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.internal.SonarWSClientFacade.getUnresolvedRemoteIssuesRecursively(SonarWSClientFacade.java:170)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.remote.RemoteSourceCode.getRemoteIssuesRecursively(RemoteSourceCode.java:107)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.doRefreshIssues(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:131)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.fetchRemoteIssues(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:120)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.run(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I would appreciate any help. Also I would like to know if there is a way to suppress my custom rule for some of the java file. I have seen the options like `//nosonar` and `@supress()`. Please let me know the way to suppress my custom rule for some java files.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse ? of SonarQube Plugin for Eclipse ? and of SonarQube ?

Comment: Sonarqube server version : 5.4, sonarlint version : 2.0, Eclipse(release 2(4.4.2))

Comment: Now it is working after switching from sonarqube eclipse plugin to sonarlint  2.0 plugin.  I want to ask that, i created a java rule and the rule result i am able to see in the sonarqube UI, but that i am not able to see in my eclipse after analysis. javaFileScannerContext.addIssue(importTree, this, "Avoid imports (3rd party imports)");

Comment: does sonarlint works with custom rules:  https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-248

Answer (score 1):

It Seems that this is a version issue. sonarqube eclipse plugin does not work with sonarqube 5.4 server.
If you are using sonarqube 5.2+ server. you have to use sonarlint eclipse plugin for the analysis.

Comment: FYI, requirement for SonarQube server 5.2+ (for connected mode) is [known and documented](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html) (so is [SonarQube Eclipse Plugin depreciation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse)).