# sonarlint(eclipse) not reporting error for my Java custom rule

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube5.3, sonarlint-eclipse

I have created a sonarqube custom rule for Java. It seems to be working when I check it in the sonarqube server UI.

I have configured sonarlint with my eclipse but sonarlint is not reporting any error for my custom rule. How shall I add that, so that the sonarlint displays the error for my custom rule after analysis.

I am using:

```
javaFileScannerContext.addIssue(importTree, this, "Avoid imports (3rd party imports)");
```

to add the issue. How can this issue be reported on eclipse side?

Answer (score 3):

SonarLint does not yet support rules from custom plugins, see [MMF-248](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-248) .

Comment: I am using sonarqube server 5.4, with sonarlint 2.0. If i use sonarqube eclipse plugin it gives me "Synchronization error". please see my another post :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685596/sonarqube-synchronization-error?noredirect=1#comment60975266_36685596

Comment: You will have to wait for the feature to be implemented in SonarLint before you can use custom plugins/rules with SonarLint.

Comment: If thats the case, i tried sonarqube eclipse plugin, where is get "Synchronization error".  I have written the error here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685596/sonarqube-synchronization-error/36706474?noredirect=1#comment61015746_36706474                        can you please give a look to it and let me know how shall i fix it